# java.lang.NullPointerException: Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, I'll try to explain my mistake slowly, point by point.

1. I have a mobile app made according to your tutorial. I watched the video and did it. Then I corrected and improved the errors.
2. Completed the functionality of writing to the question, by analogy to your tutorial.
   Everything seems to be working fine, there are no questions. Everything works..I collected a working APK.
   I thought it was cool.
3. There was a lot of extra stuff in my database: Testuser1, testuser2, and so on. I went to delete all of them. Deleted it first in the Real-time database, then in the Firestore. However, while deleting I accidentally touched something message in the document.
4. Now I get an error in a new app, working earlier than the APK and the version from a week ago.
5. Error: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference**

`firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.startListening();`

I have been struggling with the problem for at least 2 days, I wrote to many thematic communities, technical support all without success. The error is not in my java code, but in my misklik in Firebase. I want to create a missing document in my case.

I have already tried to recreate applications, pass debag, etc., but all to no avail.

My data structure is Firebase Realtime Database:
[![My data structure is Firebase Realtime Database:][1]][1]

Just in case, here is the code for my simplified activity:

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageButton sendbtn, cambtn, back;
    TextView username, typingtv;
    EditText messageEt;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference rootref1, rootref2, typingref;
    MessageMember messageMember;
    Boolean typingchecker = false;
    String receiver_name, receiver_uid, sender_uid, url;
    Uri uri;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
 
 
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            url = bundle.getString("u");
            receiver_name = bundle.getString("n");
            receiver_uid = bundle.getString("ruid");
            sender_uid = bundle.getString("suid");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 
        messageMember = new MessageMember();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_message);
        cambtn = findViewById(R.id.cam_sendmessage);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MessageActivity.this));
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.iv_message);
        messageEt = findViewById(R.id.messageet);
        sendbtn = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonsend);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username_messageTv);
 
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);
        username.setText(receiver_name);
 
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
 
 
        if (user != null) {
            sender_uid = user.getUid();
            if (receiver_uid != null && sender_uid != null) {
 
                rootref1 = database.getReference("Message").child(sender_uid); //getReference("Message")
                rootref2 = database.getReference("Message").child(receiver_uid); //getReference("Message")
 
            }
 
        }
 
        sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SendMessage();
            }
        });
 
        cambtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
 
 
        messageEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }
 
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {  }
 
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { }
        });
 
 
    }
 
 
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 
 
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE || resultCode == RESULT_OK ||
                data != null || data.getData() != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
 
            String url = uri.toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, SendImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("u", url);
            intent.putExtra("n", receiver_name);
            intent.putExtra("ruid", receiver_uid);
            intent.putExtra("suid", sender_uid);
            startActivity(intent);
 
 
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "no file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
 
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
 
 
        if (rootref1 != null) {
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MessageMember> options1 =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessageMember>()
                            .setQuery(rootref1, MessageMember.class)
                            .build();
 
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessageMember, MessageViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter1 =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessageMember, MessageViewHolder>(options1) {
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MessageMember model) {
 
                            holder.Setmessage(getApplication(), model.getMessage(), model.getTime(), model.getDate(), model.getType(),
                                    model.getSenderuid(), model.getReceiveruid(), model.getSendername(), model.getAudio(), model.getImage());
 
 
                        }
 
 
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                    .inflate(R.layout.message_layout, parent, false);
 
                            return new MessageViewHolder(view);
                        }
                    };
 
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter1.startListening();
           recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter1);
 
        }
    }
 
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void SendMessage() {
 
        String message = messageEt.getText().toString();
 
        Calendar cdate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
        final String savedate = currentdate.format(cdate.getTime());
 
        Calendar ctime = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat currenttime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        final String savetime = currenttime.format(ctime.getTime());
 
        String time = savedate + ":" + savetime;
 
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to send empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            messageMember.setDate(savedate);
            messageMember.setTime(savetime);
            messageMember.setMessage(message);
            messageMember.setReceiveruid(receiver_uid);
            messageMember.setSenderuid(sender_uid);
            messageMember.setType("t");
 
            String id = rootref1.push().getKey();
            rootref1.child(id).setValue(messageMember);
 
            String id1 = rootref2.push().getKey();
            rootref2.child(id1).setValue(messageMember);
 
            messageEt.setText("");
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I corrected my question by shortening it by 100 lines. The problem now is similar, it does not connect users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Having solved the problem, I have prepared a couple of answers for people with a similar problem. My solutions have been working for more than 2 weeks at the time of writing the answer.

1 is the simplest, it can work. Delete the Firebase database in real time. Create the JSON file again and attach it to the application again. It helped me, but only for a while.

2-Perform a thorough debugging, especially check the data transfer to Firebase. Getting information from the user. Getting information in FB

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `rootref1` may not yet be initialized when you call this in `onStart`:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MessageMember> options1 =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessageMember>()
                .setQuery(rootref1,MessageMember.class)
                .build();
```

That seems to happen because you only conditionally initialize it in `onCreate` with:

```
if (user != null) {
    sender_uid = user.getUid();
    if ( receiver_uid != null && sender_uid != null) {

        rootref1 = database.getReference("Message").child(sender_uid).child(receiver_uid);;
        rootref2 = database.getReference("Message").child(receiver_uid).child(sender_uid);;

    }
}
```

My best guess is that you only want to initialize the adapter and start the listener if there is a user, so in `onStart` you'll also want to check if `user != null` or if `rootref1` is initialized:

```
if (rootref1 != null) {
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MessageMember> options1 =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MessageMember>()
                    .setQuery(rootref1,MessageMember.class)
                    .build();
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, this prevents the error. It doesn't crash the app, but unfortunately it doesn't link it to the right user. Do you need more detailed information? I can add it. In addition, I went through the debug and for some reason eceiver_uid returns null. Although in the next class with a similar job, everything works. Is there any way to contact you personally for more information? My telegram: @HarshBarash

Comment: You posted about a null pointer exception, which is what I addressed in my answer. If you're thinking that there should be a signed in user, consider using an auth state listener, like shown here: https://gist.github.com/puf/9818068b3be173c40cdcf56d2cc59029. That means your code gets called when the user state changes, and you can create/start the adapter in there.

Comment: The problem is slightly different. This is surprisingly working code, but the problem is in Firebase. I accidentally deleted the column and now it can't pull up the data, resulting in receiver id = = null.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very different problem, so I'd recommend posting a new question about it. But in general, Firestore can't query for documents that don't have a certain field. There's no way around this, which is why it's common to give fields a default value - and consider backfilling the field in the documents where you accidentally deleted it.

Comment: How do I correctly formulate a question on this topic? And yes thank you.